# Thymeleaf dynamic datatype for form

Tags: java, spring, forms, hashmap, thymeleaf

I have a HashMap, providing the data for certain documents:

```
 Key   |   Value
 ----------------
 Name  |   test1
 Type  |   type1
 ...
```

Number of rows is not specified and both, Keys and Values, are Strings at first.

Now i want to edit this dynamic data. Therfor i created this template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/documents/{id}(id=${doc_id})}" th:object="${properties}" method="post">
    <h1 th:text="${document_h1_text}">Documents</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="property : ${document_properties}">
            <td th:text="${property.key}">Property</td>
            <td>
                <input name="${property.key}" th:value="${property.value}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `document_properties` is related to a `HashMap<String,String>`

This works fine when i GET this web service with

```
@RequestMapping(path = "documents/{doc_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String document(@PathVariable long doc_id, Model model) { ... }
```

Now i want to edit this output in the front-end and submit the changes:

```
@PostMapping("documents/{doc_id}")
public String editDocument(@PathVariable long doc_id, @ModelAttribute HashMap<String, String> properties,Model model) { ... }
```

Unfortunately the HashMap `properties` is empty when i call it thorugh clicking on the "Submit" button. Does anybody of you know how to solve this problem? FYI: I deliberately chose to not using conventional class binding here. The reason is that i want get a dynamic solution, working with arbitrary classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're going to need a wrapper around the Map at the very least (I don't think you can bind straight to a Map in the way you want it to work).
2. You should always be using th:field instead of th:name and th:value when possible.

Here's a quick example that should work the way you want it to.

Wrapper

```
public class MapWrapper {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MapController {
    @GetMapping("map.html")
    public String get(Map<String, Object> model) throws Exception {
        MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();
        wrapper.getMap().put("1", "One");
        wrapper.getMap().put("2", "Two");
        wrapper.getMap().put("3", "Three");

        model.put("wrapper", wrapper);
        return "map";
    }

    @PostMapping("map.html")
    public String post(Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute("wrapper") MapWrapper wrapper) throws Exception {
        return "map";
    }
}
```

Form

```
<form action="map.html" th:object="${wrapper}" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="key : ${wrapper.map.keySet()}">
            <td th:text="${key}" />
            <td>
                <input th:field="*{map[__${key}__]}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has overbidding  backing object and don't seems a good way , I think we need some generic pattern such :

```
public class GenericEntity {
protected Map<String, Object> properties = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 
//setter getter
}
```

where `entity extends GenericEntity`
and in controller

```
  <tr th:each=" key : ${wrapper.map.keySet()}">
       <td th:text="${key}" />
       <td>
        <input th:field="*{properties[__${key}__]}" />
       </td>
  </tr>
```

but you should find a way to set properties map in super class and it is so hardcoded , the other way may write down custom dialect for thymleafe v3 .